# How to get user's location in flutter's official mapbox package?

Tags: flutter, dart, location, mapbox

I'm using the package [mapbox_maps_flutter 0.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_maps_flutter). And I can't find a way to get the user's current location **coordinates**.

I can only update `LocationComponentSettings` that don't have coordinates. I'd like to have a method `getUserLocation()` or `getLastKnownLocation()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get current position from mapbox in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58751473/how-to-get-current-position-from-mapbox-in-flutter)

Comment: @Andrej I'd not really like to use an additional package, but as a last resort I'll use it. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t think it possible to get the current location using mapbox package. The only solution is to use another package. That’s how it is with cross-platform frameworks, or you can write native code and implement the functionality yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:

```dart
Position? userLocation = await mapboxMap?.style.getPuckPosition();

if (userLocation != null) {
   print('Location: ${userLocation}');
}
```

```dart
extension PuckPosition on StyleManager {
  Future<Position> getPuckPosition() async {
    Layer? layer;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      layer = await getLayer("mapbox-location-indicator-layer");
    } else {
      layer = await getLayer("puck");
    }
    final location = (layer as LocationIndicatorLayer).location;
    return Future.value(Position(location![1]!, location[0]!));
  }
}
```

Then `userLocation` has `Position?` type (see package  [turf](https://pub.dev/packages/turf)). However, you must first enable location tracking:

```dart
mapboxMap?.location.updateSettings(LocationComponentSettings(enabled: true));
```